# Fortran 90 Array - Diamond Shape

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have a dataset, and it looks like this.

```
1  2  3  4  5  
2  3  4  5  6  
3  4  5  6  7  
4  5  6  7  8  
5  6  7  8  9
```

This is the desired output:  (Nothing is recorded with an X value).

```
X  X  3  X  X  
X  3  4  5  X  
3  4  5  6  7  
X  5  6  7  X  
X  X  7  X  X
```

When it writes, I should get "`3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 7`" as output.

I have tried a lot of ideas so far and at this moment, nothing seems to be working.  My `do` loops end up creating lots of output and/or it reads the wrong values.  I have even tried messing around with different storage modes, but nothing seems to be applicable.

Comment: You should probably show your code.

Comment: Is it a homework? It is not hard to write a program solving this, but you should learn how to understand bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you had the foresight to declare your array like this

```
integer, dimension(-2:2,-2:2) :: my-array
```

that is, with the centre element having index (0,0) then I think this nested loop will output the elements in the order you require:

```
do row = -2,2
    do col = -2+abs(row), 2-abs(row)
        write(*,*) my_array(row, col)
    end do
end do
```

If you did not have the foresight to declare your array that way, the arithmetic is a little more fiddly (but no worse than that) so I'll leave it to you.  And for a production code you'll want to replace all those `2`s with a parameter or a call to `ubound` or `lbound`.